# How to retrieve gps co-ordinates of my iPhone to my server to show on my website?

Tags: iphone

I'm working on a security app on iPhone. I want to show the real time position of users iPhone ,any time when user clicks "find device" on website.(provided- user has installed my app on iphone and has registered on my website.)

In my previous webservices what I used to do is,request to server for some information and server would respond the request.(using NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection from device)

But here the case is, my device is not requesting the server for some response;user will be requesting the server from website to locate the device. 
here I cant use NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection.

I can get my gps co-ordinates on my iphone programmatically. issue is, just to pass those co-ordinates to my server ONLY when server is asking my device to do that.
How should I achieve that??

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The only way to say, 'ping' a device with data is with [apns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service) - and that won't invoke a handler for you, that'll just send a notification to the device. Make the app periodically send back its location to the server with a background handler - that's all you can do.

Comment: How the apps like 'lookout security' works? I guess they don't periodically send its location to the server.when we request to find device on their website,it shows connecting... and within 1-2 mins, location gets displayed.It may be from server side they are doing something to communicate to device. any idea?

Comment: I would imagine they're using background handlers to stay alive by keeping a BSD socket open.